# "They live ten miles north of Boston."—Does it mean "10m from the north of Boston to the north" or "from the north of Boston to an unknown direction"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, adverbial-phrases, adverbials

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/north_3):
**(1)** *They live ten miles north of Boston*.

What does it literally mean?:
**(1a)** Being in the north of Boston, we should go ten miles north in order to come to them.
**(1b)** Being in the north of Boston, we should go ten miles somewhere (we don't know where: south, north, east or west) in order to come to them.

Comment: Sense 1b would *never* apply. The two possibilities are either your sense 1a, OR (far more likely in most contexts) they live *10 miles to the north of the **centre** of Boston*. In the UK, if a road sign says *London: 10 miles*, that normally means ***to the city centre***. I expect the same applies in other Anglophone countries, but I'm not sure.

Comment: To me your question doesn't make good sense. "to an unknown direction" --- what do you mean?  The phrase means that the city of Boston is south of where they live, and the distance is about 10 miles, since few people use such phrases precisely. And it is not necessarily due south. Boston could be southwest of them if they live on the coast or southeast of them if they live inland.

Comment: And how the distance is being measured is unknown, whether from the city limits or from downtown.  The phrase is not intended to be understood in precise terms.

Comment: "Ten miles north of X" literally means ten miles in a northerly direction from X. It makes no mention of exactly where the measurement begins.  Not sure why you are confused here.

Comment: Where **northerly** encompasses due north, north-by-northwest, and north-by-northeast.

Comment: **Being *in Boston*, we have to go ten miles to get to them**.

Comment: "Being in Boston" is not *entailed* by "They live ten miles north of Boston." The deixis has been fabricated out of whole cloth.

Comment: @Lovii Could you please stop presenting us with multiple choices, where we have to pick one or more of your formulations as valid? In this particular case, the original phrase has no deictic implications, and all of your options introduce deixis.

Comment: @TimR "Presenting multiple choices" helps me to understand not only what variant is correct but also what variant is incorrect. The latter helps me dial with the difficulties I encounter in leaning English much better than the former. I'm convinced the real "leaners' dictionary" must explain not how to use words correctly (this function completely lies on usual "non-learners' dictionaries") but rather how we should not use words. If there were such a dictionary, learning English would be much easier.

Comment: @Lovii  Why do you think in this particular instance the statement "They live 10 miles north of Boston" has anything to do with where your "we" happen to be?

Answer (score 2):

From Boston (considered by the speaker to be a point-like location) go 10 miles north.  Ten miles north of Boston would actually bring you to the little Lincolnshire Village of [East Kirkby](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/East+Kirkby,+Spilsby+PE23+4BY/@53.1413739,-0.0167257,15z/) (unless you meant the *other* Boston; Boston MA is a big city and ten miles north of the downtown is still in the Boston conurbation)

Such descriptions are not normally intended to be detailed enough to identify exactly where someone lives, only give a general idea  (It is close enough to drive, to too far to walk to Boston daily)

Comment: There are tons of towns ten miles north of the city of Boston, MA. You might have checked that.

Comment: That would ruin the joke...  Anyway, Boston MA  doesn't have a clear "location".  Do you measure from downtown, the northern part of the administrative "city", or the north of the metropolitan area.  By using Boston, Lincs you can measure "10 miles north" and find a specific location.

Comment: I guess I didn't get the joke, James. The city of Boston is clearly delineated: It has an area of 48.4 sq mi (125 km2)[10] and a population of 675,647 as of 2020. Wikipedia. :)

Comment: "10 miles north of London" (England) would be ambiguous, since the metropolis is about 30 miles across.

Comment: All this was fully covered by my comment under the question. The only justification for keeping the question open is if people think the ***Anglophone*** version of "distance to town/city" consistently differs from non-Anglophone interpretations of the same basic reference (i.e. - is it the distance to the ***nearest boundary*** or the ***centre*** of the specified location). I see no evidence that the OP has even *considered* this fundamental distinction, so I'm closevoting as "matter of opinion".

Comment: @FF do you mean you answered in a comment? Well -  don't do that.